# Real Eigenvalues and Similarity

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, jordan-normal-form, similar-matrices

Let $A$ be a complex $n \times n $ matrix.

a) Prove that if all the eigenvalues of $A$ are real, then $A$ is similar to a real matrix.

b) Classify up to similarity all the matrices $A$ such that $A^n=I$

My attempt:

a) Since the eigenvalues are real, the characteristic polynomial will split. So there exists a Jordan canonical form $J$ such that $A=Q J Q^{-1}$. Hence, part a) proved.

b) We want $I=A^n= (QJQ^{-1})^n= QJ^n Q^{-1}$.

So we must have $J^n=I$. We know that $J$ depends on the eigenvalues and their multiplicities. From here, I'm not sure how to continue.

Could someone please check my part a) and let me know how to continue with part b)?

Thank you!

Comment: Part A is incorrect: the matrix $\;\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\;$ has only real eigenvalues but its characteric polynomial, $\;P(t)=(t-1)^2\;$ doesn't split (can you see why?)

Comment: What is wrong at $a)$? The Jordan canonical form of the matrix is similar with $A$ and has all entries from $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: How do you know that $Q$ is real?

Comment: @DonAntonio What is wrong with repeated linear factors?

Comment: I see what you mean now, but does $Q$ need to be real? I mean, does similarity imply that $Q$ also has to be real? Isn't it enough for $J_A$ to be real?

Comment: @alien2003 Depends on whether similar means over the reals or complex.

Comment: Oh, ok then ,thanks!

Comment: @copper.hat as far as I remember, when speaking of char. polynomials of square matrices saying "its splits" means it can be written as a product of "different" linear factors $\;\iff\;$ the matrix is diagonalizable...

Comment: @DonAntonio I am not strong on algebra, but I think splitting just means linear factors.

Comment: @copper.hat That is true in general algebra. It may be that I'm wrong but I have that idea about, precisely, the char. polynomial of matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $b)$, because $A^n=I_n$, the minimal polynomial of the matrix divides $X^n-1$ and this polynomial has n distinct roots so the minimal polynomial will also have distinct roots, so the matrix is diagonalizable.

Now let $A=QDQ^{-1}$

Because $A^n=I_n$, $D^n=I_n$ but if we consider $D=diag(d_1,d_2,...,d_n)$, then $D^n=diag(d_1^n,d_2^n,...,d_n^n)$ so the matrices that you are looking for are the matrices that have their Jordan canonical form a diagonal matrix and that have their eignvalues roots of unity of order $n$, i.e. $d_i=e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n}}$, where $k\in\{1,2,...,n\}$.